# Angular form *ngfor with template variable and two way binding

Tags: angular, iteration, ngfor, angular-template-variable

I have looked into several posts with this kind of problem but did not find a solution.

description:

- Everything is shown with the last object value "profession" on init (model.overview : IOverview)
- Binding seems to work when I change it.
- Template variable does not work it will be red (when any field is invalid) for all or green for all otherwise...

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of objectKeys(model.overview)">
    <div class="col form-group">
        <label for="item">{{item}}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item" required [(ngModel)]="model.overview[item]" name="item"
            #inputmodel="ngModel" #spy>
        <div [hidden]="inputmodel.valid || inputmodel.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
            {{spy.className}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

code:

```
model = new Hero('uuid', this.overview);
objectKeys(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj);
}
```

Result Page load:
[image: result:]
Result when I edit some input fields:
[image: result when I input some fields:]

Where do I go wrong here?

EDIT1: Here is the resulting html: http://codebin.herokuapp.com?s=5e6e7688a569680004000006

EDIT2: Adding the initial picture on page load (green)

Comment: could you add the resulting htm to the op?

Comment: So, you are not able to apply the alert class conditionally?

Comment: Tha altert div seems not the have a "unique" scoped tempalte variable attached to it... (kinda merged)
And the values in the Input fields are alwas "profession" even though when I type something in it is correctly set.
@pero_hero what do you mean htm? do you mean html? I cann add that.

Comment: could you try to use an index in your *ngFor in order to have unique ids?  `*ngFor="let item of objectKeys(model.overview); let i = index"` and id="'item'+i"

Comment: The IDs are now unique: I used `for=item{{i}}` and `id=item{{i}}`
https://pastiebin.com/5e6e901acaca9

But the problem with the alert and the wrongly initialized form persists still...

Comment: edditing`name=item{{i}}` did the trick! Nice! I will update this with an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using a `uni-diractional binding {{}}` and an index `i`.
Thanks to @pero_hero for helping me find a simple solution!

Here is the final code:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of objectKeys(model.overview); let i = index">
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label for=item{{i}}>{{item}}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id=item{{i}} required [(ngModel)]="model.overview[item]"
          name=item{{i}} #inputmodel="ngModel" #spy>
        <div [hidden]="inputmodel.valid || inputmodel.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
          {{spy.className}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```